# ¿SQL puede leer datos por un puerto?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, socket

Estoy conectando un PLC con una base de datos SQL Server 2012, el PLC fue configurado para enviar datos string mediante TCP/IP por medio de un socket, cree una aplicacion en C# que por medio de ese mismo puerto recibe la cadena string, y la manipula para enviarla a insertar a SQL.

Ahora esta es mi pregunta:

**¿Hay una manera de programar dentro de SQL para recibir datos por un puerto?**

Ocupo hacerlo lo más directo posible, no he encontrado información al respecto, o ¿solo de puede con un intermediario como en este caso?.

Agrego: El PLC no lleva ninguna programación dentro de él, solo se configura para que envíe cadenas de string a un puerto. Leí que SQL escucha a través del puerto 1443, lo cual es para conexiones remotas, sin embargo yo creo un puerto con mi aplicación para escuchar y enviar a SQL.

Comment: El lenguaje SQL por sí solo no manipula conexiones a sockets. Ahora, las funcionalidades del motor de base de datos que se use, esas `tal vez` ofrezcan algo parecido a lo que buscas. Se necesitan más detalles de lo que intentas hacer. **SQL <> SQL Server**
PD. SQL Server usa el puerto 1433 para *recibir* conexiones e iniciar sesiones en la BD. No es claro cuando dices que "creas un puerto con tu aplicación"

Comment: @Alfabravo Me refiero a que en la aplicacion creo un socket para escuchar el PLC, le asigne el numero 2000, y en el PLC le indique que enviara datos al puerto 2000, esto esta funcional, mi pregunta era si directamente del PLC se pueden enviar datos al puerto 1443 de SQL o alguna funcion que se paresca a esto.

Comment: Pues de poderse, se puede. Tú simplemente necesitas iniciar una sesión en la BD (nivel de aplicación) comunicándote mediante paquetes TCP al puerto 1433. Lo que no sé es si en el PLC puedas poner toda la lógica para crear la sesión, ejecutar la consulta y cerrar la sesión.

Comment: Te recomiendo investigar KepServer y PI Server, kep puede escuchar por puertos y puedes conectar N cantidad de PLCs, PI Server es mas efectivo para almacener y consultar datos, algo que sql server no puede hacer.

Comment: me temo que directo no podrias ya que no solo es enviar cualquier cosa al puerto de sql server, sino que necesitas de un proveedor que entienda que enviar. Vas a tener que crar algo intermedio que use un proveedor que pueda traducir lo que envias del PLC y lo transforme a lenguaje de consulta SQL